# System does not let go of the handle after closing executable

Tags: windows-7, process, 64-bit, system, handle

after i execute .exe and .bat files and close them, system does not let the handle go for about a minute. it forces me wait to build/save the file.
this pisses me off so much when i m editing bat files or building executable.

here are 2 screenshot to show what i mean
1st is the all active processes, (maybe there is some oddity i'm not aware?)
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/processak.jpg/

2nd is system's handle on bat file.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/696/handlek.jpg/

thank you.

Comment: Do you have any security software installed?

Comment: i dont. also i'm running a just 2 weeks old windows 7 install.

Comment: That's certainly enough time to pick up some nasty rootkit.  This isn't on topic here, try superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have finally found the problem.

Reactivated Application Experience and Program Compatibility Assistant Services.

i now build and delete as often as i like.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the command line utility "Handle" ([available from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655)) to see if it gives you any more info.